# 32-bit Linux x86 assembly code and trash at output

Tags: assembly, x86

I am doing some coding today and with help from other topic I tried to do my own program. The idea of it is to change the value I put at the beggining (it's ascii) to a normal value. So, what I want to see in console:

1. Number [A-1, .., Z-26] A
2. 1

The output when i enter A would be 1, B would be 2, etc.
The output I GET is tons of trash..

Here is my code:

```
SYSCALL = 0X80
SYSEXIT = 1
SYSREAD = 3
SYSWRITE = 4
STDIN = 0
STDOUT = 1  

.data
.align 32

NUMBER_MAXLEN = 2
NUMBER: .space NUMBER_MAXLEN
NUMBER_LEN: .long 0

MSG_NUMBER: .ascii "Number [A-1, .., Z-26] "
MSG_NUMBER_LEN = . - MSG_NUMBER

.text
.global _start

_start:

#show
mov $SYSWRITE, %eax
mov $STDOUT, %ebx
mov $MSG_NUMBER, %ecx
mov $MSG_NUMBER_LEN, %edx
int $SYSCALL

#read
mov $SYSREAD, %eax
mov $STDIN, %ebx   
mov $NUMBER, %ecx
mov $NUMBER_MAXLEN, %edx
int $SYSCALL

#length
sub $1, %eax
mov %eax, NUMBER_LEN

#Change to normal value
xor %eax, %eax
movb NUMBER, %al
sub $'A', %al
add $1, %al
movb %al, NUMBER

#Print
mov $SYSWRITE, %eax
mov $STDOUT, %ebx
mov $NUMBER, %ecx
mov $NUMBER_LEN, %edx
int $SYSCALL     

END:
mov $SYSEXIT, %eax
int $SYSCALL
```

What I am doing wrong? How can it be well.. repaired?

Comment: I checked values (with gdb) under NUMBER, and after (sub $'A', %al
add $1, %al
movb %al, NUMBER) it's like 68000 instead of 1.. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `__nr_write` syscall (4) simply prints strings, it doesn't act as a `printf` function. So you need to convert the number into its string representation before you print it.

Here's some pseduo-code illustrating how that could be done:

```
char buffer[10];
char *p = &buffer[9];

*p = 0;  // NULL terminator
do {
  p--;
  *p = (number % 10) + '0';
  number /= 10;
} while (number != 0);

print(buffer);
```

Comment: This code doesn't help me.. I don't understand it. Can you explain it, or just the method with converting?

Comment: All it does is repeatedly add a character from '0'..'9' to a string buffer´in a backwards order. If the number was 25 it would write '5' to the buffer, then divide 25 by 10 to get 2. So on the next iteration it writes '2' to the buffer, divides 2 by 10 to get 0, at which points it stops. The buffer at that point contains '2', '5' (and the NULL terminator that was added at the start), i.e. the string "25".

Comment: Besides the itoa problem, `movl $NUMBER_LEN, %edx`moves the address of `NUMBER_LEN` into `$edx` - way too many characters to print. Lose the '$'. This is why you're getting "tons of" garbage instead of just a character or two...

Answer (score 0):

If the user enters "Z", you want to print "26"?  You could use a lookup table, or do some conversion yourself.
INTEL/NASM format:

```
%define SYSCALL  0X80
%define SYSEXIT  1
%define SYSREAD  3
%define SYSWRITE  4
%define STDIN  0
%define STDOUT 1  

%define NUMBER_MAXLEN 2
section .data

MSG_NUMBER: db "Number [A-1, .., Z-26] ", 0
MSG_NUMBER_LEN equ $ - MSG_NUMBER

section .bss

NUMBER:         resb NUMBER_MAXLEN
NumToPrint      resb 3
NUMBER_LEN:     resd 1

section .text
global main

main:

;show
    mov     eax, SYSWRITE
    mov     ebx, STDOUT
    mov     ecx, MSG_NUMBER
    mov     edx, MSG_NUMBER_LEN
    int     SYSCALL

;~ #read
    mov     eax, SYSREAD
    mov     ebx, STDIN
    mov     ecx, NUMBER
    mov     edx, NUMBER_MAXLEN
    int     SYSCALL

;~ #length
    sub     eax, 1
    mov     NUMBER_LEN, eax 

;~ #Change to normal value
    movzx   eax,  byte [NUMBER]
    push    eax
    call    IsValidChar
    test    eax, eax
    js      main                            ; not valid input, repeat prompt

    push    NumToPrint
    push    eax
    call    dwtoa                           ; convert to ASCII

;~ #Print
    mov     edx, eax
    mov     eax, SYSWRITE
    mov     ebx, STDOUT
    mov     ecx, NumToPrint        
    int     SYSCALL    

End:
    mov     eax, SYSEXIT
    int     SYSCALL

;~ #########################################    
IsValidChar:
    mov     eax, [esp + 4]

.0to9:
    cmp     eax, "0"
    jb      .NoGood
    cmp     eax, "9"
    ja      .AtoZ
    jmp     .NoGood

.AtoZ:
    cmp     eax, "A"
    jb      .NoGood
    cmp     eax, "Z"
    ja      .atoz
    sub     eax, 64                         ; convert letter index to number equiv.
    jmp     .Done

.atoz:
    cmp     eax, "a"
    jb      .NoGood
    cmp     eax, "z"
    ja      .NoGood
    sub     eax, 96                         ; convert letter index to number equiv.
    jmp     .Done

.NoGood:
    xor     eax, eax
    dec     eax
.Done:
    ret     4
```

You will need to create your own dwtoa (DWORD to ASCII).

[image]